# Add/Remove editors in Google sites using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites-2016

I am writing a google apps script to process bulk add/remove editors for some new Google Sites.
I am aware that google apps script currently doesn't support new google sites so I am trying to use DriveApp to manage the editors.
However the script doesn't work and returns the following:

Exception: Service error: Drive

whenever `file.addEditor()` or `file.removeEditor()` is used. I guess this just doesn't work for new Google Sites.
Are there other workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the correct `FileId` with Sites as it's not quite as simple to acquire compared to other file types on Google Drive. When you're editing a Site page, the `FileId` can be found in the URL between `/d/` and `/p/`.

Example: `https://sites.google.com/d/????? this the file id ?????/p/!!!! not here !!!!/edit`

I just successfully ran the below code to add/remove editors of a new Google Site.

```
const zFile= DriveApp.getFileById("????? this the file id ?????");

function addEditor(){
  zFile.addEditor("pgsystemtester@gmail.com");
}

function removeEditor(){
  zFile.removeEditor("pgsystemtester@gmail.com");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment about the id...I didn't know that about sites

Comment: @Cooper, you bet. I didn't include it in my original answer however I figured that was the leading cause of this question's issue since OP had the proper method. I feel like there is a desperate need for Google App Scripts to interact more fluidly with the new Sites structure.

Comment: I'd like that for sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It solved my problem. I thought the bunch of text after /p/ was the file id. The strange thing was that I could actually get the file using the text after /p/ as the file id.

Comment: @KaiChungCheung I figured as much as I stated above. Happy to help, glad it worked, thanks for accepting.